# why this function in this class doesn't work correct in lua?

Tags: lua

I run this code in lua:

```
cal = {num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0,num4 = 0,num5 = 0,num6 = 0}
function cal:new (n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6)
    local self = {}
    setmetatable(self,cal)
    self.num1 = n1
    self.num2 = n2
    self.num3 = n3
    self.num4 = n4
    self.num5 = n5
    self.num6 = n6
    return self
end
ea = cal:new(1,2,3,4,5,6)

ae = cal:new(7,8,9,10,11,12)

for k,va in pairs(ea) do print(va) end
for k,va in pairs(ae) do print(va) end
```

and this is the output:

> 1 
> 2
>  5
>  6
>  3
>  4
>  7
>  8
>  11
>  12
>  9
>  10

why this numbers has been messed up???

Comment: Is `num1`, `num2`, etc. supposed to represent different field names, or are you literally using numbers 1-6 in your table keys? If the latter, you could just use an array instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pairs` traverses a table in an unspecified order.

The [manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-next) says

> The order in which the indices are enumerated is not specified, even for numeric indices.

(That's in the entry for `next`, on which `pairs` is based.)

Comment: Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Lua does not store table keys in any particular order. One way to print fields in order would be to add another method:

```
function cal:print()
  print(self.num1)
  print(self.num2)
  print(self.num3)
  print(self.num4)
  print(self.num5)
  print(self.num6)
end
```

Comment: I want a shorter answer.

Comment: Shorter in what way? I wrote the answer like this, because I don't want to make any assumptions about what you need.